# Scheduling a cron job that initiates H2o fails in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, cron, ubuntu-16.04, h2o

When scheduling an R script with crontab scheduler that initiates an H2o instance locally it fails with the following error:

```
Starting H2O JVM and connecting: 
............................................................
[1] "localhost"
[1] 54321
[1] TRUE
[1] -1
[1] "Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused"
[1] 7
```

When I run it without cron, it is working just fine. 
Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Please share relevant part of the script that is producing this output. Is it running under the same user?

Comment: The part of the script where it fails is the line h2o.init(). Indeed, it is running under the same user.

Comment: Can you provide H2O log? I recommend redirecting the output to a file. We should see on what network interface H2O used. I've never seen this behavior before so I need more details